# passing parameters in jsp from a form

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have below,

1. Student.java -> contains method to add Students in the database
   addStudent(int id, String name,String address,String class)
2. AddStudentServlet.java -> Controller to interact with the db and jsp
3. AddStudent.jsp -> JSP form to add students
4. Student table in mysql with columns id, name, address, class

When I submit the form with all values its fine. However when I enter partial values ie. in id, name fields, I get an error saying number of parameters do not match.

How can I change the model to allow partial addition of fields in the db?

Comment: Where the error "number of parameters do not match"? Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: -1: Paste some relevant code or the relevant stack-trace for the error. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in your `DAO` this error is being thrown by `database` where `insert in to @tablename` you have less number of column values. i.e. you have defined 4 column but passing values 3 only.

`how can i change the model to allow partial addition of fields in the db?`

In insert SQL pass those column as null if they are not entered in form but keep complete insert statement

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query must include values for **all** of the table columns. So you can not add a student record with less than 4 fields.